# Execute a web service using netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, jdbc, netbeans

I want to make one web service that, communicates with one database on localhost. The name of the database is "Reservation" and has only one matrix with the name "seats". This table has 4 fields: (int) ID, (varchar) location, (varchar) class (int) taken. For example, one record has the following fields: ID=1, location="Window", class="Economy", taken=0. I want my web service update one record that's the taken field is zero.

My code is:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService( name = "Reservation", serviceName = "ReservationService" )
public class ReservationSOAP
{
   private static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/Reservation";
   private static final String USERNAME = "root";
   private static final String PASSWORD = "root";

   private Connection connection;
   private PreparedStatement lookupSeat;
   private PreparedStatement reserveSeat;

   // a WebMethod that can reserve a seat
   @WebMethod( operationName = "reserve" )
   public boolean reserve( @WebParam( name = "seatType" ) String seatType, @WebParam( name = "classType" ) String classType )
   {
      try
      {
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection( DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD );
         lookupSeat = connection.prepareStatement( "SELECT ID FROM seats WHERE taken = ? AND location = ? AND class = ?" );

         lookupSeat.setInt( 1, 0 );
         lookupSeat.setString( 2, seatType );
         lookupSeat.setString( 3, classType );

         ResultSet resultSet = lookupSeat.executeQuery();

         // if requested seat is available, reserve it
         while ( resultSet.next() )
         {
            int seat = resultSet.getInt( 1 );
            reserveSeat = connection.prepareStatement( "UPDATE seats SET taken = 1 WHERE ID = ?" );
            reserveSeat.setInt( 1, seat );
            reserveSeat.executeUpdate();
            return true;
         } // end if

         return false;
      } // end try
      catch ( SQLException e )
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
      } // end catch
      catch ( Exception e )
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
      } // end catch
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            lookupSeat.close();
            reserveSeat.close();
            connection.close();
         } // end try
         catch ( Exception e )
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
         } // end catch
      } // end finally
   } // end WebMethod reserve
} // end class Reservation
```

The problem is that the web method returns False because the database is not updated.

Comment: What's the stacktrace you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off - you should use try-with-resource. Your statement `reserveSeat` might still be `null` inside your `finally` block throwing a NullPointerException, causing false to be returned. The `ResultSet` is **never** closed.

You comment `//end if` on the closing brace on a `while()`

I'd recommend local variables for your code.

Consider this changed implementation. I've also thrown in some `System.out.println` that enable you to check if the parameters received would actually work in your SQL.

```
@WebService(name = "Reservation", serviceName = "ReservationService")
public class ReservationSOAP {
    private static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/Reservation";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";

    // a WebMethod that can reserve a seat
    @WebMethod(operationName = "reserve")
    public boolean reserve(@WebParam(name = "seatType") String seatType,
            @WebParam(name = "classType") String classType) {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                PreparedStatement lookupSeat = connection
                        .prepareStatement("SELECT ID FROM seats WHERE taken = ? AND location = ? AND class = ?")) {
            System.out.println("seatType: " + seatType);
            System.out.println("classType: " + classType);
            lookupSeat.setInt(1, 0);
            lookupSeat.setString(2, seatType);
            lookupSeat.setString(3, classType);

            try (ResultSet resultSet = lookupSeat.executeQuery()) {

                // if requested seat is available, reserve it
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    int seat = resultSet.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println(
                            "Found unreserved seat: " + seat + " in class " + classType + " and seatType " + seatType);
                    try (PreparedStatement reserveSeat = connection
                            .prepareStatement("UPDATE seats SET taken = 1 WHERE ID = ?")) {
                        reserveSeat.setInt(1, seat);
                        reserveSeat.executeUpdate();
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println("No Seat found.");
            return false;
        } // end try
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    } // end WebMethod reserve
} // end class Reservation
```